# How to Use the Correct Google Map Code in Jquery Tabs?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, maps

Can someone help me correctly integrate Google maps in jQuery tabs.

I need to integrate 2 maps.

One map that retrieves the Map, and another map that retrieves the route planner.

I have a problem with the code, I get this error in Firebug:

```
TypeError: a is null
[Break On This Error]   

... new S((this.H+this.J)/2,(this.G+this.L)/2)};var zh=yh(-ca,-ca,ca,ca),Ah=yh(0,0,...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js` in a script tag then lazy-load it again in an onload handler causing the original to be overwritten and negating some of the code that executes before `initialize()` `initialize2()`.

Comment: how can i integrate this code corect? and how can i integrate to display 2 maps on same page... that is the problem...and have no errors.. thanks for reply

Comment: Yes, I know. First get rid of the double load, then track down other bugs. You don't need to load the Google script twice to get two maps.

Comment: yes,but i don't know how to load in jquery tabs 2 maps..if i delete one `script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";` it display only one map

Comment: i delete 2 lines
`   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";`

Comment: If you are working on WordPress you probably should use `wp_enqueue_script('gmap?sensor=false&callback=initialize', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js')` and prevent to load scripts in-line. More here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: use wath ? i dont understand

Comment: Beetroot it work if i delete that links but in first map the map is not in center...

Comment: I guess you have found out that Google maps will only initialize properly if the canvasses are visible? You can either (a) start with the canvasses visible, initialise then hide, or (b) start with the canvasses hidden, then initialise when first shown.

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting this error due to using the same variable name for the map:

```
var map = ...
```

Try using 2 different variables:

```
var map, map2;

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_go"), myOptions);
map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_go_full"), myOptions);
```

Comment: It works, but i recive an error - Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

Comment: @MioBocereg Are you including the API multiple times? makes sure you don't have more than one instance of this code in your page: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js